# Remove files created through mount & owned by root

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have been doing some trial & error learning about bind mounts in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04...

I got everything working the way I wanted it, but as a result of my trial & error learning the root of my Ubuntu install is cluttered by folders that don't belong there, but don't seem to want to be deleted.

What I did wrong: I didn't know `/etc/fstab` doesn't play well with spaces in mount point names... I didn't know spaces should be replaced with `\040`.

So I added these lines to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
!!!WARNING!!!
This messed up my root folder so don't use it...

"/media/seed-1ab/DATA2/SWR/01 Speciale Tekens" "/home/seed-1ab/rtorrent/seeds/01 Speciale Tekens" none bind
"/media/seed-1ab/DATA2/SWR/02 Cijfers" "/home/seed-1ab/rtorrent/seeds/02 Cijfers" none bind
"/media/seed-1ab/DATA2/SWR/03 A" "/home/seed-1ab/rtorrent/seeds/03 A" none bind
"/media/seed-1ab/DATA2/SWR/04 B" "/home/seed-1ab/rtorrent/seeds/04 B" none bind
```

Then I rebooted & discovered that these spaces weren't a good idea.
During boot I got these errors saying that `A" couldn't be mounted`, `Speciale wasn't recognised as filesystem type`, `B" couldn't be mounted`, etc...

That's when I knew something was wrong so I started researching & quickly found what I already mentioned above... don't use spaces in `/etc/fstab`.

That being said, I fixed it & got it working. After some while though, I discovered that there were additional folders in `/` that weren't there before... `A"`, `B"`, `C"`, `Speciale`, `Cijfers"`, etc...
These folders are owned by root and that's about all I can tell about them.

If I try to remove them using `sudo` or as root the terminal appears to hang with a blinking cursor next to a `>` sign until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
root@ivanUbuntuServer:/# rm -R A"
> ^C
```

How do I get rid of these folders?

Comment: Boot in from a live CD/USB would be one option to alter this back

Comment: see [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](//askubuntu.com/q/890782)

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -R A"
```

or

```
sudo rm -R A"
```

doesn't work (not even as root) because " is a special character which must be escaped with a backslash \ otherwise it's interpreted by the shell (and that has nothing to do with permissions or ownership of the file/folder).
Since all the foldernames (except Speciale) start with a letter & end with a " you can delete them all with one command:

```
rm -ri *\"
```

This command removes files and directories including their contents (`-r` for recursive) ending with a `"` and asks for confirmation before removal (`-i`).

Since the folder `Speciale` doesn't contain any special character, it can be removed by just typing

```
rm -ri Speciale
```

(`-i` isn't strictly necessary, but it's a good idea to use this when using `rm` with a glob, as it might match something you don't actually want to delete)